# Optimize SQLite query that has multiple parameters using FMDB

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, fmdb

I have a query that starts pretty simple:

```
SELECT zudf16, zudf17, zudf18, zudf19, zudf20, zitemid, zItemName, zPhotoName, zBasePrice FROM zskus WHERE zmanufacturerid=? AND zudf16=? ORDER BY zItemID
```

As choices are made I build on it:

```
SELECT zudf16, zudf17, zudf18, zudf19, zudf20, zitemid, zItemName, zPhotoName, zBasePrice FROM zskus WHERE zmanufacturerid=? AND zudf16=? AND zudf19=? AND zudf20=? ORDER BY zItemID
```

For each parameter I add the query drops in performance, especially on iPad1.  Each of these columns have an index on them.

How can I increase the performance of this query as it get's more targeted rather than lose performance?

This is across around **60,000 records** that match the initial ManufacturerID but with a total of about **200,000 rows** total in the database.

Comment: Are you are always filtering down from the initial query each time?

Comment: no exactly, there is a list of 5 options and they can add and remove them as they wish, I thought of just searching the results every time they add a filter but if they pick filter 1 and then filter 2 and then remove filter 1 and choose filter 3 I have to start from scratch but that might be my best best - initial search on 1 filter and then do then filter the rest from the result.